# Best method to copy a file to the SQL Server machine

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr, sqlbulkcopy

I am looking into copying a file from the client computer to the server computer. One path I've looked into was creating a CLR method which accepts a stream as input. Another suggestion I've had is to use the BCP utility, though I have been unsuccessful in finding any examples which this was done using BCP.

Is it possible to pass a blob to BCP and import to a table, or would there be more steps involved to make this work?
Which method would be best for a file copy functionality?

Comment: Are you trying to move the file from client system to server, or from client system into database?

Comment: The overall goal is from client into db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can BCP blobs in and out of the database.  Also, I found a reference to scripts for importing and exporting files as blobs which [might be helpful](http://makdns.blogspot.com/2012/02/sql-server-blob-import-and-export.html).